# Comparing distance of two matrices with different sizes using eqdist.etest function in R

Tags: multivariate-analysis, matrix, euclidean

I want to compute a test statistic based on the Euclidean norm of two data matrices with same number of columns (i.e variables) but very different number of rows (i.e observations). 
I am using the eqdist.etest function from the energy package which requires that I combine the two matrices as the first step.

Can you tell me what is the most accurate way to make this comparison ?

Is the problem of having different sizes defined in eqdist.etest?

Comment: Please tell what platform you are using.

Comment: Oh, it is in R! Please also look at the answer that I just found.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any objective or correct way to answer this question without at least knowing (a) what this test statistic actually is and (b) why the sizes of the data matrices differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my answer.

- To my *second* question: Yes, different sample sizes are defined in eqdist.etest. After we combine the rows using rbind(), in the arguments of the test we can specify the two sizes.
  Example*:

  ```
  eqdist.etest(X, c(20, 20), distance=TRUE, R = 199)
  ```
- And to my *first* and main question: The row (i.e observation) sizes need to be the same, and the function above fills the gap in sizes using [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) (the last argument)

This is my understanding. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

[*] Ref: R documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/energy/versions/1.7-5/topics/eqdist.etest).